# How to get number of channels for a video file in opencv?

Tags: c, opencv, video-capture

How can I get the number of channels used by my video before initiating a capture?
I thought I could use `cvGetCaptureProperty` but there is no property_id I could set to get the number of channels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're right - there are no `property_id` for number of channels. You can get number of channels only from single frame of capture.